# Is it possible? Matching the exact same number of opening & closing braces

Tags: regex, qt

I'm no expert on Regex. I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match the exact same number of opening and closing braces, but I'm stumped on how to do it.

An example:

```
nothing: important, a b { c {{{ a another {{ nothing }} }}} }
```

or:

```
one { two {{ error, forgot ending brace }}
```

The problem is that I don't know how many braces I'm going to get beforehand. In the first example, I need to get the text `{ c {{{ a another {{ nothing }} }}} }`. In the second I need to get `{{ error, forgot ending brace }}`.

Is it even possible to create a matching rule that will do this? (I'm using Qt Regex engine).

Comment: I'd try using string function. Something similar to PHP's strpos().

Comment: Even if it is possible with regex, you will end up with a long and dirty regex that'd make you hate yourself the day you need to modify it. Better use a stack.

Comment: Are your brackets always as nicely spaced out as in your example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem cannot be solved using regular grammar => it cannot be done by regular expression.

However - from Dirk Vollmar's comment - certain regex engines have extended functionality, e.g. the .NET one, which is capable of matching brackets using so called ["balanced group definitions"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2005/03/15/net-regular-expressions-regex-and-balanced-matching-ryan-byington/).

Comment: I think it can be solved with REGEX pretty easily, with repeatedly  matching the output of the expression "{(*.)}", but that's worse than using simple string function.

Comment: True, such a language is not regular. However, certain regex engines have extended functionality, e.g. the .NET one, which is capable of matching brackets using so called "balanced group definitions": http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx. QT unfortunately doesn't support that (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qregexp.html, "Note that in general regexps cannot be used to check for balanced brackets or tags. However, it is possible to write a regexp that will match nested brackets or tags correctly, but only if the number of nesting levels is fixed and known. If the number of