# Decoding/reading json part of complex text file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

I am starting to develop a desktop application using Electron. This app will parse some files and datas will be shown from these files. These files are containing complex data.

Now, I am trying to get json data from a complex text file. This text file contains some string and json objects. Sample file looks like that:

```
    ...strings that I'm not interested in...
    { 
        "partOneA":0,
        "partOneB":7,
        ....
    }
    ...randomly strings may stand between json sections...
    {
        "partTwoA":7,
        "partTwoB":4,
        "partTwoC":4,
        ...
    }
    {
        "differentPartA":3,
        "differentPartB":5,
        "differentPartC":6,
        ...
    }
    ...somemoretext....
```

The problem is that, how can I get the json parts from this complex file using *javascript*? Performance of the solution should be considered.

**Additionaly**, Consider that json structure is nested like that:

```
{ 
    "partOneA":0,
    "partOneB" :{
        "partOneBnode1":0,
        "partOneBnode2":7,
        }
}
```

Resolving with regular expressions is not applicable for this issue.
Now, I am trying to find a javascript based solution.

Comment: Mind that `{ "partOneA" = 0 }` is not valid JSON whereas  `{ "partOneA" : 0 }` is.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can rely on `{` and `}` as starting and closing tags you could use a regex like:

```
var jsonRegex = new RegExp(/({(?:(.|\n)*?(?:[^\\])){0,1}?})/g);
var result = jsonRegex.exec(text);
var firstMatch= result[1];
```

As a result you should get the first piece with the subsequent matches at the subsequent indexes. You can read the docs [here on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec[1];).

You can play around with regex on sites like http://regexr.com/

**Note**

This approach does not work with nested JSON because you would require to match the same amount of opening and closing brackets (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415882/3737186)).

Comment: I can't try this right now, but I have a question on my mind. I think this does not work, If I have nested json structure like this:
 
 { 
  "partOneA"=0,
  "partOneB" :{
   "partOneBnode1"=0,
   "partOneBnode2"=7,
   }
    }
 
 But I will try more about regular expressions, thanks.

Comment: Yes this approach does not work with nested JSON. Maybe add this as a requirement to your question. This could indicate you should not use Regex for this problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415882/3737186)