# How can I use regular expression to match the img tag an html string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove `img` tag from an HTML string, but when I used regexp to match the `img` tag with ">" in the attribute value of the `img`, it always match the wrong substring.

Here is a case:

```
var str = '<img src="test>test" alt="test > test test" > "some text';
var reg = ???
```

How to make `'<img src="test>test" alt="test > test test" >">'.match(reg)[0] === '<img src="test>test" alt="test > test test" >'`

Tried this regexp `/<\s*(img)[^>]+(>[\r|\n|\s]*<\/\1>|\/?>)/`, but not worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible? Matching the exact same number of opening & closing braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415872/is-it-possible-matching-the-exact-same-number-of-opening-closing-braces)

Comment: You don't, Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)....

Comment: `const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.querySelector('img').outerHTML);`

Comment: @cyberbrain there's no matching braces in the OP's case

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev braces, quotes, smaller/greater signs, where is the difference?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, I can't use DOM-related API here.

Comment: So if you are in node, you can use libraries that do it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js  You might just be tracking down edge cases with your regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img` - starting a tag
`[^">]*` - any number before the first `"`
`(?:"[^"]+"[^">]*)*` - any number of `"` pairs with no `"` inside the pair plus any number of chars except `"` and `>` after the pair
`>` - closing

```js
const tests = ['<img src="test>test" alt="test > test test" > "some text', '<img> <img>', `<img
src="test">`];

tests.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(/<img[^">]*(?:"[^"]+"[^">]*)*>/g)));
```